# How to return IAsyncOperation<TReturn> result?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I want to perform CPU intensive work asynchronously. I thought to use code like this one:

```
   ....
   updateGUIObj = await setSelectedGUICellValueAsync(arg1, arg2, cssId, isInitializeCbxChecked);
   ....


   public IAsyncOperation<UpdateGUIObj> setSelectedGUICellValueAsync(int arg1, int arg2, String cssId, bool isInitializeCbxChecked)
   {
        updateGUIObj = new UpdateGUIObj();

        ....  // compute intensive work setting "updateGUIObj" 

        return ?????;
    }
```

How should I write the above `return` statement?

Comment: Why don't you use the Task api? Task.Run will execute in another thread if needed and returns a Task which is awaitable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **async/await** pattern and returns `Task<>` objects instead:

```
...
var updateGUIObj = await setSelectedGUICellValueAsync(arg1, arg2, cssId, isInitializeCbxChecked);
...

public async Task<UpdateGUIObj> setSelectedGUICellValueAsync(int arg1, int arg2, String cssId, bool isInitializeCbxChecked)
{
    var updateGUIObj = new UpdateGUIObj();

    // .... compute intensive work setting "updateGUIObj" 

    return updateGUIObj;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Returning `IAsyncOperation<TResult>` is necessary if you're writing a WinRT component. However, I recommend writing the `IAsyncOperation<TResult>` code just as a simple wrapper around the more natural `async`/`await` implementation.

There's an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779745(v=vs.110).aspx) that was written specifically for this scenario:

```
public IAsyncOperation<UpdateGUIObj> setSelectedGUICellValueAsync(int arg1, int arg2, String cssId, bool isInitializeCbxChecked)
{
  return SetSelectedGuiCellValueAsync(arg1, arg2, cssId, isInitializeCbxChecked).AsAsyncOperation();
}

private async Task<UpdateGUIObj> SetSelectedGuiCellValueAsync(int arg1, int arg2, String cssId, bool isInitializeCbxChecked)
{
  updateGUIObj = new UpdateGUIObj();
  await Task.Run(....);
  return updateGUIObj;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen. From my initial reading of this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443%28vs.110%29.aspx) I thought I had to return a `IAsyncOperation<TResult>`. With your comment I re-read it and it is now clear I only need to return a `Task<TResult>` as proposed in the above solution.